# htaccess redirect in case of 404 error for paged results

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I migrate from Joomla to WordPress my web site and now I have many 404 errors in Google WebMaster tools because of the tags paged results.

In example in my Joomla I had the URLs

http://www.mysite.com/tag/rain/page/4/

http://www.mysite.com/tag/rain/page/5/

...

http://www.mysite.com/tag/rain/page/x/

Now in WordPress I don't have in example the URLs from page 5 to x and that creating 404 errors.

Also I cannot permenent redirect them to something else, because at the feature I will create new posts with that tags, and the missing pages will be again available.

So is there a way to redirect that pages if they produce 404 errors to another destination, but only for the case that the page return 404 error ?

Kind regards

Merianos Nikos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page

Especially the parts:

- Creating an Error 404 Page
- Help Your Server Find the 404 Page

As these methods you can do redirects based on their need.